# Maximal Subfield of $\mathbb C$ without $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: galois-theory

If we let $K$ be a maximal subfield of $\mathbb C$ that doesn't contain $\sqrt{2}$, then if $L$ is any finite extension of $K$, then its Galois with a cyclic 2-group. I want to  use this to conclude that $[\mathbb C:K]$ is countable and not finite. I know that $\mathbb C$ is algebraic over $K$.

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I sort of have an idea for the not finite part: if it were finite, then $\mathbb C$ would be a cyclic extension of $K$, and so it would have a unique index 2 subfield. If I can prove that the only index $2$ subfield of $\mathbb C$ is $\mathbb R$, then I think I can finish the argument, since $K$ "should" contain imaginary elements (though I'm not too sure how to prove this either).

For countable, does the fact that every complex number is a root of a polynomial in $K[x]$ and the fact that $[K[x]:K]$ is countable work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Algebraically closed fields with proper maximal subfields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86395/algebraically-closed-fields-with-proper-maximal-subfields) at MathOverflow for a succinct answer (shorter than the one I wrote, until I recognized it as one I had read over there, looked up the reference, and deleted my answer).

Comment: Hmm, so it seems that $\mathbb R$ is not the only index $2$ subfield...can I still modify my argument to work? or is there a simpler way to conclude that it's not finite?

Comment: @Nishant: Troublingly, the accepted answer shows that $[\mathbb{C}:K]$ (your $K$, not Laurent Moret-Bailly's $K$) is finite (in fact, $2$).

Comment: Wait, really?! This is an exercise from Dummit and Foote, and this is not on the errata...

Comment: Seems relevant:  http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf

Comment: Wait, that just says that if $K$ WERE of finite index, it would be of index $2$. i guess that's why it's NOT of finite index...?

Comment: Which part of Laurent Moret-Bailly's argument do you think does not apply to your problem?

Comment: So if $[\mathbb C:K]$ were finite, it would be of index $2$, but I'm not sure how to derive a contradiction from that...

Comment: The question you linked to deals with maximal subfields.  In particular, it must be that $K(\alpha)=\mathbb{C}$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} - K$.  But for this question, $K$ is only maximal with respect to the condition $\sqrt{2} \notin K$.  There are many extensions of $K$ which are not $\mathbb{C}$: $K(\sqrt{2})$ (does not contain $\sqrt[4]{2}$), $K(\sqrt[4]{2})$, etc.