# A maximal field not containing $\sqrt{2}$ revisited

Tags: field-theory, axiom-of-choice

The following basic result has been discussed [numerous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598507/the-maximal-subfield-of-mathbb-c-not-containing-sqrt2) [times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836973/does-a-maximal-subfield-of-mathbb-c-not-containing-sqrt2-have-index-2) on this forum.

> The set of subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ not containing $\sqrt{2}$ has an inclusion-maximal element.
>
> *Proof.* If $K_1\subset K_2\subset\ldots$ is a chain of such subfields, then their union is still a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that does not contain $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore, the result follows from [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma).

Let me recall that Zorn's lemma is an equivalent reformulation of the Axiom of Choice. Therefore, this proof does not give any explicit construction of such a field. Can we do without Choice?

Comment: Aside: I think you could prove the existence of a maximal algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with that property. A maximal subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ with that property is another question.

Comment: You may find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411705/do-maximal-proper-subfields-of-the-real-numbers-exist helpful.

Comment: @Hurkyl The algebraic version of the question is still interesting to me. Can you please give a hint?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think this is a different question. The question you mean seems to ask if there is a field $K$ such that $K(\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{R}$ .

Comment: It is a different question – but it still might be helpful.

Comment: @Heptagon: The key point is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is, like any countable set, well-orderable. I believe there's a theorem that any well-orderable field has a unique (up to isomorphism) well-orderable algebraic closure, and you should be able to use a well-order on that to do whatever transfinite iteration you need. (note that, I think, that without AoC it's possible that it may have other algebraic closures as well, but they won't be well-orderable)

Comment: @Hurkyl: You are correct about your last comment.

Comment: I ***think*** that @Gerry is correct. If $F$ is a maximal subfield of $\Bbb C$ such that $F(\sqrt 2)=\Bbb R$, then $K=F\cap\Bbb R$ is a subfield of $\Bbb R$ such that $K(\sqrt 2)[\sqrt{-1}]=\Bbb C$. In which case, the two questions---the one here, and the one linked by Gerry---are equivalent.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for the explanation! Maybe I should create a sister question for algebraic numbers instead of $\mathbb{C}$ in order to keep your answer recorded. I don't know if I am allowed to do so by the rules here though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, but I do not understand why is my question equivalent to those that you discuss. It seems easy to me to get that a field $K$ can satisfy $K(\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{R}$ or $K(\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{C}$ only if $K$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, but I do not see how to get the answer to my question from there.

Comment: You can create as many questions as you like, heptagon, but if they are related then please make sure you link each to the others.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, @GerryMyerson!